# HDFStore append to dataset - works for smaller subset, breaks for larger subset

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am loading a high dimensional dataset (90*80000) into a chunked pandas dataframe. Using HDF5store I want to write this dataset to .hdf5.
I am partitioning the dataset into a matrix **90*6** and anpther **90*remaining columns**.

I am using the approaches outlined in the cookbook and tried different solutions that I found scattered across the internet - to no avail. I think the problem might be, that the header of the second partition is too big (considering the 64kb limitation). However, I think I am passing only the matrix, not the entire dataframe to the `.append` command.

This is my code:

```
i=0
reader = pd.read_csv(dataFile, delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=10, names=header, skiprows=1)
    for chunk in reader:
        # if i==0:
        #     print chunk.ix[:,6:].values
        #     store['df'] = chunk.ix[:,6:]
        #     print type(store['df'])
        #     print store['df'].shape
        # else:
        #     store.append('df', pd.DataFrame(chunk.ix[:,6:]))
        #     print store['df'].shape
        store.append('a',chunk.ix[:,6:])
        store.append('ID', chunk.ix[:,:6])         #the only command that works
        chunk.ix[:,6:].to_hdf(store, 'df', format="table", append=True)
        store.append('df', chunk.ix[:,6:].values)
        i+=1
```

These are a bunch of options that I tried individually with none of them working, except for the small data subsection. The commented version writes the first chunk to the dataset but then complains that it can only append to 'tables'.

The general error message:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/OneDrive/Research/2016 Research Project/python files/rawToHdf5TutChunked.py", line 109, in
> >     
> >         store.append('a',chunk.ix[:,6:])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 919, in
> >     append
> >         **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1264, in
> >     _write_to_group
> >         s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3801,
> >     in write
> >         self.set_attrs()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3052, in
> >     set_attrs
> >         self.attrs.non_index_axes = self.non_index_axes   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tables\attributeset.py", line 461, in
> >     **setattr**
> >         self._g__setattr(name, value)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tables\attributeset.py", line 403, in
> >     _g__setattr
> >         self._g_setattr(self._v_node, name, stvalue)   File "tables\hdf5extension.pyx", line 715, in
> >     tables.hdf5extension.AttributeSet._g_setattr
> >     (tables\hdf5extension.c:7315) tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5
> >     error back trace
>
> File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5A.c", line 259, in H5Acreate2
>       unable to create attribute   File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5Aint.c", line 275, in H5A_create
>       unable to create attribute in object header   File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5Oattribute.c", line 347, in
>   H5O_attr_create
>       unable to create new attribute in header   File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5Omessage.c", line 224, in
>   H5O_msg_append_real
>       unable to create new message   File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5Omessage.c", line 1945, in
>   H5O_msg_alloc
>       unable to allocate space for message   File "J:\dev\src\hdf5_1_8_cmake\src\H5Oalloc.c", line 1142, in **H5O_alloc
>       object header message is too large**
>
> End of HDF5 error back trace
>
> Can't set attribute 'non_index_axes' in node:  /a (Group) ''. Closing
>   remaining open files:t.hdf5...done

I am not used to working with large datasets so any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround that works nicely now. I dropped using HDF5Store, though. 
Basically I am creating a dataset using h5py and overallocate it, then trim empty rows afterwards:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(datafile, delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=args.chunksize, names=header, skiprows=1)
max_rows_est = 880000   #estimate for maximum number of rows per file
i=0                     #counter for no of iterations through loop
n_rows=0                #counter of no of processed rows

for chunk in reader:
     big_chunk_shape = chunk.ix[:,6:].shape
     if i == 0:
         print 'creating dataset {0}'.format(j+1)
         dset2_data = f_hdf5.create_dataset('{0}'.format(j+1), (max_rows_est, big_chunk_shape[1]), maxshape=(None, big_chunk_shape[1]), dtype='<i4')
     dset2_data[i*big_chunk_shape[0]:(i+1)*big_chunk_shape[0], :] = chunk.ix[:,6:].values
     n_rows += big_chunk_shape[0]
     i+=1

dset2_data.resize((n_rows, big_chunk_shape[1]))
```